# unable to create DynamoDB table from aws CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I am very new to aws. I was trying to create a database table by running following command:
``

```
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name pizza-order --attribute-definitions AttributeName=orderId, AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=orderId,keyType=HASH --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnit=1,WriteCapacityUnit=1 --region us-east-2  --query TableDescription.TableArn --output text
``
```

But I am getting a error like this:
**Error parsing parameter '--attribute-definitions': Expected: '', received: '' for input:
AttributeName=orderId,**

Comment: AttributeName=orderId, AttributeType=S, can you remove the space between `orderId and AttributeType and its KeyType,and ReadCapacityUnits same goes for WriteCapacityUnits` and why are you using `--query TableDescription.TableArn --output text` what you want to achieve with ``query option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command works with following modifications:

- Remove space after orderId,
- KeyType correctly capitalized
- ReadCapacityUnits and WriteCapacityUnits correctly pluralized.

Here is the working command for your reference:

`aws dynamodb create-table --table-name pizza-order --attribute-definitions AttributeName=orderId,AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=orderId,KeyType=HASH --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1 --region us-east-2 --query TableDescription.TableArn --output text`

Comment: after dong that it gives following error. can u tell me what to do!?  An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateTable operation: User: arn:aws:iam::676374644948:user/suraiya_moon126 is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:CreateTable on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-2:676374644948:table/pizza-order

Comment: you need to atach a policy to your Iam user by going to users in iam -> under permission add permissions -> attach existing policies directly -. search for dynamodb full access and add it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
aws dynamodb create-table --table-name pizza-order --attribute-definitions AttributeName=orderId,AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=orderId,KeyType=HASH --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=1,WriteCapacityUnits=1 --region us-east-2 --query TableDescription.TableArn --output text
```

Docs for reference
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/getting-started-step-1.html

To verify that DynamoDB has finished creating the Music table, use the describe-table command.

```
 aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name pizza-order | grep TableStatus
```

This command returns the following result. When DynamoDB finishes creating the table, the value of the TableStatus field is set to ACTIVE.

```
"TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
```

note:- whenever you are stuck or want to know the details of the command its a good practice to check aws cli doc for particular API [for create table](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/dynamodb/create-table.html)